# Storing Information After Python Console is Closed

Tags: python

I was coding a "game" in pygame and wanted to store `highscore`, as a variable that takes the player's highest score and saves it. I would want it to look something like this:

```
if score > highscore:
     highscore = score
```

Maybe I could save this in a separate text file, any suggestions??

Edit: I want to be able to close the console between times playing the game and still have the highscore save

Comment: Writing to a text file would work and is what many games do.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the JSON library that is built-in to Python 3:

You just have to import the library, make a dictionary with the highscore set, stringify, and save.

```
import json

savedata = {}

def exportSavedata():
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(savedata, outfile)
```

After that, just make a function that loads the high-score, and run it whenever the game starts:

```
def loadSavedata():
    with open('path_to_file/person.json') as infile:
        savedata = json.load(infile)
```

Then just use the savedata dictionary to store game data and high scores, and run the save function to export it to the file.

Comment: Viable answer for sure, storing to file requires the least prerequisites. Use a dictionary `{}` as the answer shows and you'll get very simple and obvious JSON outcomes.